# Trying to prove, that an initial spatial and restricted displacement on an infinite string, with a density discontinuity, will transmit AND reflect

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, reflection, string, vibrations

This is a rather trivia problem, but I have been trying to prove it, since all of the Books I have read - online or not - take it for granted.

The problem I'm talking about is "Vibration of String" but with a discontinuity on density, lets say;

$$\rho(x) = \bigg( \dfrac{\rho_1 - \rho_2}{2}\bigg)(2 \Theta(x)-1) + \dfrac{\rho_1+\rho_2}{2}$$

Now, we produce an initial vibration - or displacement -  which, for the shake of simplicity, let's define it as simple as it takes: $$y(x)=2A\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi(x+L)}{L}\bigg)\quad for \quad -L < x < 0$$

The problem is well known and one can find the solutions on many books, here is one Online Chapter which pretty much covers the Vibration of String like any book out there

`2.7 - Page 11` on this link `https://personal.egr.uri.edu/sadd/mce565/Ch2.pdf`

One can see that the reflection is taken for granted. In particular, it says that when the waves reach the Density Discontinuity, the transient displacement left and right of Zero will be $$ Y_- = Y_{incident}+Y_{reflected} \quad \quad\ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  Y_+ = Y_{Transmitted}$$ and here is where my curiosity appeared, because until now, everything was plausibly proven using the wave equation \begin{equation}\dfrac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial t^2}-\dfrac{T}{\rho(x)}\dfrac{\partial ^2 y}{\partial x^2} =0 
\quad  \quad A
\end{equation} where  $T$ is constant

I have been trying for about 2 days, to prove that  once the initial vibration reaches $x=0$ reflection and transmission will appear- For our problem the initial displacement looks like this:[image: Hand Made Initial Vibration on Our string]

There  will be two waves travelling, one left and right, using D'Alambert Method, one can easily prove that

$$Y_{left}(x)=A\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi(x +\sqrt{T/\rho_1}t+L)}{L}\bigg)\quad for \quad -L < x +\sqrt{T/\rho_1}t < 0$$
AND
$$Y_{right}(x)=A\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi(x -\sqrt{T/\rho_1}t+L)}{L}\bigg)\quad for \quad -L < x - \sqrt{T/\rho_1}t< 0$$

Obviously the right one is the one which will "collide" with the discontinuity. But given the only known equation is A - `\ref` didn't work - no reflection is "proven" or taken for granted.

What someone can do is try again with D'Alambert methods to solve this on the right string,  and connect it with the left string, demanding velocity/displacement and derivative to $x$ to be the same on $0_{\pm}$

For those who don't remember, the solution is in the form of $$ Y_+ = f_1(t\sqrt{T/\rho_2} +x) +f_2(t\sqrt{T/\rho_2}-x)$$

and the previous demands - One can prove them be Integrating the A equation on $0 \pm \epsilon $  - are written in the form of

$$\partial_x f_1(t) +\partial_x f_2(t) = \dfrac{A\pi}{L}\cos\bigg(\dfrac{\pi(L-t\sqrt{T/\rho_2})}{L}\bigg)\quad for \quad -L < -t\sqrt{T/\rho_2} < 0$$

AND

$$ f_1(t) +  f_2(t) = A\sin\bigg(\dfrac{\pi(L-t\sqrt{T/\rho_2})}{L}\bigg)\quad for \quad -L < -t\sqrt{T/\rho_2} < 0$$

And those are the ONLY boundary conditions I have managed to include. Energy conservation should play a role but haven't managed to place it, and I'm still not close to proving the reflection more strictly, rather than taking it for granted.

Any bit of help, is much appreciated because this has been very frustrating.